# How to get number of activities that satisfy implicit intent?

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm using implicit intent to, say, open Gallery to pick an image. I'm normally doing the following:

```java
Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI)
    .takeIf { it.resolveActivity(activity.packageManager) != null }
    ?.let {
        val intent = Intent.createChooser(it, "Choose gallery")
        activity.startActivityForResult(intent, rc)
    }
```

But if that **intent** is resolved by just single application on my device, and there is no other gallery app but one, then **chooser** will only display single choice which is useless.

How could I figure out whether there are many activities that could handle that **intent**? How to get the number of activities that actually fit? And hence, decide whether to show **chooser** or not.

Comment: from: 

```val info: ResolveInfo = activity.packageManager.resolveActivity(it, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY)```

**info: ResolveInfo** will contain some vendor-specific Activity package and classname that will be used to resolve implicit intent and display multiple choice, if there are multiple choices actually. Otherwise it will contain package and classname for single appropriate Activity. But in any case i cannot figure out, neither there are multiple choices nor single choice, and i can't know that single choice in advance.

Comment: Why not show a chooser with one app? It's still a chooser in the sense that it gives the user the choice to leave your app and use the one on the menu, or ignore the menu and stay in your app instead?

Comment: The Product requirement is not to show choose with single app, because this forces user to perform additional taps, etc. This simply makes no sense to have chooser with single choice.

The app's UX is clear that user intentionally clicks on some button to, say, add image. I think it's app's responsibility to allow user to 'cancel', not for an external component (such as chooser).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How could I figure out whether there are many activities that could handle that intent?

Call `queryIntentActivities()` on a `PackageManager`, supplying your `Intent`.

> How to get the number of activities that actually fit?

Sorry, but I do not know what "fit" means in this context.

> And hence, decide whether to show chooser or not

You could simply get rid of the `Intent.createChooser()` call. You only use that when you wish to *force* the user to *have* to deal with a chooser. If you leave `Intent.createChooser()` off, **the system will show a chooser on its own** when needed. That occurs if:

- There are 2+ activities that match the `Intent`, and
- The user has not chosen a default activity for that `Intent` structure

BTW, please remove `type = "image/*"` from your code. `ACTION_PICK` does not use a MIME type.

Comment: thanks, that worked.

by "fit" i actually meant the activity that could handle such intent.